# Speech to Text Converter In Xamarin Uwp

Tags: xamarin

I need to implement the audio to text converter in the Xamarin Uwp platform specific. I am able to record the audio and save that audio. But now I need to convert that audio file in to text file. If anyone can suggest me any working good example than it would be really good for me.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Speech-To-Text API in UWP, but it's moslty for commanding, e.g. executing actions based on what the user is saying. At least that's what I've seen it used for. You can read about that [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/input-and-devices/speech-recognition).

What you probably want is something like the speech recognition that Microsoft Cognitive Services offers. You can upload an audio file of up to 15 minutes and retrieve a transcript of the file. You can read about that [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/speech/).